# How to convert numpy array to R matrix?

Tags: python, r, rpy2

How do you convert a numpy array to a R matrix using rpy2? This might be trivial, but I cannot find a good answer in the documentation. I can get this working by first converting to a pandas dataframe as an extra step, but this seems redundant.

Working example:

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import *
import pandas.rpy.common as com
import rpy2.robjects as ro

B=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

Rmatrix = com.convert_to_r_matrix(B)  # Does not work

#Extra conversion via pandas dataframe
PandasDF = DataFrame(B)
Rmatrix = com.convert_to_r_matrix(PandasDF)
ro.r.assign("Bmatrix", Rmatrix)
print(ro.r["Bmatrix"])
```

Comment: Does [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10037302/489704) help?

Comment: Yes, that works, but I also found this which is even more to the point: [converting python objects for rpy2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447454/converting-python-objects-for-rpy2) @jbaums

Comment: For cases like this, should I delete or flag as duplicate?

Comment: @fileunderwater Just flag as duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

This works, based on the post [Converting python objects for rpy2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447454/converting-python-objects-for-rpy2) and the rpy2 documentation on [numpy to rpy2 conversion](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.4/html/numpy.html#from-numpy-to-rpy2):

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()

nr,nc = B.shape
Br = ro.r.matrix(B, nrow=nr, ncol=nc)

ro.r.assign("B", Br)
```